# Adding a stereotype to an attribute in Dia

Tags: uml, class-diagram, dia

Is there a proper way of adding a stereotype to an attribute (not operation) in [Dia](http://dia-installer.de/)? So far I'm inserting stereotypes to attribute names, but it has a slightly different order.

What I have:

```
+<<val>> count: Int
```

How (I think) it should look like:

```
<<val>> +count: Int
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are typing the stereotype and angle brackets. Instead, look for a way to apply a stereotype in the GUI.

Comment: You are correct, as a workaround I'm typing stereotype before attribute name. Unfortunately doing it this way visibility mark is placed before it, I would like to avoid specifying visibility to "implementation" and inserting visibility mark as a character into the name of attribute (it breaks indentation and will cause problems with code generation). I was kinda hoping for some patch or plugin. Screenshot of GUI for attribute setup is [here](http://i.imgur.com/i0BKnDs.png), I don't think I missed anything.

Comment: What tool are you using? It may have limitations.

Comment: Oh, I thought I made it clear in question (apparently, I did not :) ). I'm using Dia (added link to Q).

Comment: You might want to try a more capable UML tool, like Papyrus (free) or MagicDraw (not free). There are many others too.